# Can anyone please make this CSS work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get this css to work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephang/DXg7M/)

CSS

```
.GridContainer {
    width: 99%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.GridContainer .TopLineContainer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.GridContainer .TopLineContainer .ExtraInfoContainer {
    width: 180px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
}
.GridContainer .TopLineContainer .GuidedNavigationContainer {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
}
.GridContainer .BodyContainer {
    display: inline-table;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: Aqua;
}
.GridContainer .BodyContainer .GuidedNavigationTreeContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
    background-color: Red;
}
.GridContainer .BodyContainer .ContentContainer {
    float: left;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: Orange;
}
.GridContainer .BodyContainer .ContentContainer .ContentDataGrid {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 2400px;
}
.ContentDataGrid .ContentDataGridHeader { display: inline-table }
.ContentDataGrid .ContentDataGridHeader .Column { display: inline-table }
```

HTML

```
<div class="GridContainer">
    <div class="TopLineContainer">
        <div class="ExtraInfoContainer">
            Extra info container
        </div>
        <div class="GuidedNavigationContainer">
            guided nav container
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="BodyContainer">
        <div class="GuidedNavigationTreeContainer">
            guided nav item list
        </div>
        <div class="ContentContainer">
            <div class="ContentDataGrid">
                sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, as you can see in the jsFiddle, the orange section does not appear next to the red and its parent does not scroll.

So what should be happening is the red is on the left, the orange is on the right and the blue should scroll the orange when the content exceeds the bounds of the parent.

Comment: That looks like tabular data - why not use tables for it?

Comment: Good question.  I've been having a great deal of problems when the screen width is different for different pc's

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you want to layout your data as a grid. It's best to use a `<table>` in this case.

HTML:

```
<table class="table-grid">
    <tr><th>Extra info container</th><th>guided nav container</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="extra-info-cell">guided nav item list</td>
        <td class="guided-nav-cell">
            sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg sadfasd fasdf gadsfgkjh asdlfkgjhsdlkjfgh sldkfjhg
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.table-grid { border: 1px solid black; padding:0; margin:0; }
.table-grid th {line-height: 18px; padding:2px; }
.table-grid td {line-height: 18px; background: cyan; vertical-align:top; padding:5px; }
.table-grid .extra-info-cell { background: red; width: 160px; }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DXg7M/2/